# DB2 stored procedure for clearing the database can't be found

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, truncate, db2-luw

I'm trying to create a DB2 stored procedure that will clear all the data tables and reset the indexes to 0. The creating of the procedure is pretty straightforward, but the issue is that DB2 immediately forgets it exists. What am I doing wrong?

Create a simple script:

```
create procedure CLEARTABLES()
language sql 
BEGIN
    commit;
    truncate TABLE1 immediate;
    truncate TABLE2 immediate;
    truncate TABLE3 immediate;
END;
```

Make sure we can execute it:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE CLEARTABLES TO PUBLIC;
```

And here is where it all breaks down with `No authorized routine named "CLEARTABLES" of type "PROCEDURE" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.26.14`

```
CALL CLEARTABLES;
```

I've also tried execute, but this does not appear to do anything.

```
EXECUTE CLEARTABLES;
```

And to prove it exists:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES s  
  WHERE s.ROUTINETYPE = 'P' AND s.ROUTINENAME = 'CLEARTABLES'
```

I feel like I'm missing very obvious here so I've tried a lot of small things like parentheses, no parentheses, lower/upper case etc. I'm using DBeaver and I can see the procedure under `Application Objects > Procedures` named CLEARTABLES in all caps no parameters, yet DB2 somehow can't find it with the way I'm calling for it.

Comment: Is the procedure in one of the schemata listed in `values current path` ?

Comment: The commands are executed via JDBC where the schema is provided. In DBeaver I've set the current path to the schema manually.

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT ROUTINESCHEMA FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES WHERE ROUTINETYPE = 'P' AND ROUTINENAME = 'CLEARTABLES'` and `VALUES CURRENT PATH` in your session, where you get such an error on `CALL CLEARTABLES`?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I get a single row with the definer, the name and the schema etc. What seems to work is `call EXPERIMENTAL.CLEARTABLES();` and apparently you need to close off transactions with a commit before a truncate, but it's not going to work because I apparently have no permissions to truncate via a service, which is an issue with our DBA and put there for a good reason.

Comment: You may get such a strange situation, when you create a routine, but can't call it with unqualified name, if `CURRENT SCHEMA` registry value is not in the schema list of `CURRENT PATH` in your session. This is because unqualified routine is created in a schema equal to `CURRENT SCHEMA` value, but when you call an unqualified routine, it's searched in the schemas of `CURRENT PATH`. I did'n get, what is not going to work exactly from your comment. It's better provide exact statement you run and exact error message you get instead.